# How to add images in themes using asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

```
body
{
 background :URL(../App_Themes/(image name)no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 font-size :x-large;
}
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" Theme="Theme1"%>
```

How to add images in themes using asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Add in your Layout.cshtml css with your image like: `@Styles.Render("~/Content/YOUR_CSS")` in `<head></head>`.

This CSS with image will be show in all pages where you add your layout.